# PHP - class member type

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
class X{

}

class Y{
    private $x;

    public function printx(){
        echo $this->x;
    }
}
```

PHPStorm hints on `private $x`:

> Missing property's type declaration

But when I wrote type `private X $x;`, error in runtime:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'X' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)

Completed code is:

```
class X{

}

class Y{
    private X $x;

    public function printx(){
        echo $this->x;
    }
}
```

My PHP version is 7.3.6.
Where is the problem? How to set type of class member?

Thanks

Comment: By updating to php7.4

Comment: Or tell PhpStorm that you're using an older version of PHP, then it won't warn about this.

Comment: some light reading [rfc typed properties](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/typed_properties_v2)

Comment: @u_mulder but php7.4 is not released. How to upgrade?

Comment: Release candidate exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the PHP runtime version in PhpStorm settings to get the right hints:

```
File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP
```

In the main tab set these values:

```
- "PHP language level"
- "CLI Interpreter"
```